# What is the fastest way to reverse a comma-separated list in vim?

Tags: vim

I frequently must correct the following rails code:

```
assert_equal value, expected
```

The two arguments to assert_equal are out of order, and should read:

```
assert_equal expected, value
```

In vim, what is the most efficient way of going from the first line to the second?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Via regex:

```
:s/\v([^, ]+)(\s*,\s*)([^, ]+)/\3\2\1/
```

If you do it often you can make a map out of it, e.g.:

```
:nmap <F5> :s/\v([^, ]+)(\s*,\s*)([^, ]+)/\3\2\1/<CR>
```

Put the cursor on the line you want to flip and hit `F5`.

Answer (score 5):

This one swaps the word your cursor is on with the next one - just press F9 in command mode:

```
:map <F9> "qdiwdwep"qp
```

- "qdiw: Put the word your cursor is on into buffer 'q'
- dw: Delete all chars to the beginning of the next word (possibly comma + space)
- e: Go to end of word
- p: Paste (comma + space)
- "qp: Paste buffer 'q' (the first word)

Answer (score 1):

Map a key combination to perform the command:

```
:s/^assert_equal \(.*\), \(.*\)$/assert_equal \2, \1
```

Answer (score 1):

I've always liked regular expression search and replace for these type of tasks:

```
:s/\(\w*\), \(\w*\)/\2, \1/
```

Will swap the first word with second in a comma separated list.

Comment: Just remove the range (%). :s will operate on the current line unless you give it a range.

Answer (score 0):

Hum... I would say "tdwxx$i, ^["tp but that's not really efficient or easy, just quick enough to type...

Answer (score 0):

for something this simple, i would just make a little macro

```
qadf ea, ^[pxxq
```

then @a away