# Vim: Invert function's parameter order?

Tags: vim, editing

Suppose I got this function call:

```
cook("rice", kitchen->pot);
```

After writing that, I notice parameter order is wrong, I should have done

```
cook(kitchen->pot, "rice");
```

To fix that, I could do:

```
    1: move cursor over "rice": $b
    2: delete a ": da"
    3: move to (: %
    4: paste "rice": p
    5: insert new ,: a, 
    6: find and delete spare ,: f,x
```

But im using VIM! We edit code faster with vim, any ideas?

Comment: im looking for a solution that works for every function call and definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answers are really helpful, but I just found a solution by myself:

```
:s/\v(\w+\()([^,]+)(,\s*)([^\),]+)/\1\4\3\2
```

That will work with most kinds of parameters, and specially for my php-like function calls.

Comment: Almost seven years later and this works wonderfully for migrating from `_` to `fp` in our Javascript project. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is a similar question here which is Ruby specific but which should work for you:

[What is the fastest way to reverse a comma-separated list in vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/757338/513198)

Apparently there is no silver bullet.

Personally, I quite like soulemerge's solution.

Comment: Lots of ideas there, but none directly solves my question. They are leading only with simple parameters, like foo, bar. Im looking for a solution for: foo($array['Model'], 'field');

Answer (score 2):

With [omap-param (from lh-cpp)](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp/blob/master/plugin/omap-param.vim) + [a stuff swapping plugin](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-misc/blob/master/plugin/vim-tip-swap-word.vim), I would have typed `f(ldi,lvi,g"`. Where `di,` says *delete inner param*, `vi,` says *select inner param*, and `g"` says *swap selection with the thing we have just deleted*.

This approach may seem overkill, however unlike naive approaches it will still work with parameters like  `kitchen->getPot(medium, blue)`.

Comment: thanks, gonna try those plugins later, for now I prefer stick with native features for that

Answer (score 2):

`:map <F9> "qdt,dwep"qp`

No plugins required. Based on [soulemerge's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/757379/139), I found that this works a little better when you're dealing with code. In other words, the `iw` wasn't working well for me in the case of:

```
Assert.AreEqual(myProp.ToString(), 0xcccc);
```

If I started at `myProp`, it would only capture up to the `.`. This code just takes you up to the comma, which is particularly useful if you are swapping parameters.

Comment: Nice solution, doesnt work very well for my example, because `e` ends up in the `-` of `kitchen->pot`. Although this would work: `"qdt,dwt)p"qp`

Answer (score 0):

There is an attempt (which actually calls out to Ruby) here: https://github.com/vim-scripts/reorder.vim

It can be invoked by: `:Reorder 3,2,1`

Personally I think we can do better!  I may try to write a plugin for this...  Thinking the keybinds could be `mcl` and `mch` for Move Clause Right / Left.

As well as function arguments, I also find myself wanting to change the order of clauses in English sentences.  "I also find myself wanting to change the order of clauses in English sentences, as well as function arguments."

Another use case is items in lists which are line-separated, but for which the last argument alone should omit a trailing comma.